# PyDev says Undefined variable from import: AF_INET

Tags: eclipse, pydev

As show below, the editor displays false errors about predefined socket module. Every underlined word refers to the same message: 'Undefined variable from import: xxxxx' and 'xxxxx Found at: _socket'.

**How can I configure PyDev to avoid them?**

Python version is 3.6.9, Eclipse version is 2021.09.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The socket module information is usually loaded in a spawned python process and its contents sent to Eclipse... Sometimes this doesn't work and the usual culprit is that to get this info, a socket connection is made and this doesn't work properly.

The following faq entry: https://www.pydev.org/faq.html#HowToFixCodeCompletion has more information. Please see if you can fix it with that info (if you can't, please provide any error you have in your error log).